# Does launchUriAsync work with .edu sites?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, uri, windows-store-apps, winjs

I've created a JavaScript Windows Store blank app, and added the following code into it.

```
var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://www.google.com")
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(url);
```

when debugging my program the above launches google without fail, but if I put a .edu site or something that ends in .aspx, the site won't launch.

Comment: Can you share the .edu or .aspx sites that you were trying to reach?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?....are these sites being blocked?

Comment: www.vt.edu, these site aren't blocked

Comment: Make sure that you are using the full URI, including the http:// scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce this. Perhaps there's something in how you're doing this that's causing the issue.

To try to repro, here's what I did.

1. Started with the JavaScript Blank app template.
2. Added a button to default.html, on the line following the `<p>` element: `<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Launch" />`
3. Added an event handler for the button in default.js, just after the call to WinJS.UI.ProcessAll: `document.getElementById("Button1").addEventListener("click", launchUri);`
4. Added the launchUri function, as follows, to default.js:

launchUri:

```
function launchUri() {
    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://www.communitymegaphone.com/Default.aspx");
    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri);
}
```

Works fine for me, both with aspx (as shown above) as well as for .edu addresses.

If you're still not able to make it work, please post some additional code for context.

Hope that helps.

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I just created a new app and followed your instructions, did the exact same thing, and it works with the .aspx you shared, but when I replace it with http://www.vt.edu it doesn't launch... also that site is not blocked.. I also can't find any 'known' issues. I will try to package this exact app, and try it on another computer.. ..

Comment: As noted above in response to your original question, make sure you are using the URI scheme, and not just the domain. If I test the app I wrote with http://www.vt.edu, it works fine. If I substitute simply www.vt.edu it fails with a JavaScript error "The Parameter is incorrect." because www.vt.edu is not a valid absolute URI.

Comment: Thank you for that reminder, I have though been using the full URI. It works with any .com sites...

Comment: That seems odd. As Sandra suggested, I'd be looking at any possible network or firewall issues, and try the app not just on another machine, but if possible, on another network.

Comment: I just tried it on another machine (on the same network) and it works. I'm not sure what the issue is with this current computer.. I'll look into and if I find a reason, will post back here. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help...hope you're able to isolate the issue.